# WordPress FTP Error: "Failed to connect to FTP Server"

Tags: ftp, errors

I have an issue i've been trying to fix for two days now. I've searched the web and tried to apply multiple suggestions from other posters.

So i have a self hosting web server: CentOS7, Apache, PHP, MariaDB, OpenSSH and Pure-FTPd.

I found a nice guide combining MariaDB and pure-FTPd. I used vsftp beforehand but later found the use of database to store valid FTP users more robust and convenient.

So, I've successfully set-up ftp server and logged in with FileZilla from a remote client. I also managed to copy files and create folder in "wp-content" folder of wordpress. However when i try to use WordPress's in-house FTP solution i get a "Failed to connect to FTP Server" error. I managed to upload plugins using:

```
define('FSMETHOD', 'direct');
```

option in `wp-config.php` file. That worked and plugin was successfully installed. However i read that this is not a safe option. I am aware that plane FTP is not the safe way as well but i wanna make that work first before moving to FTPS variant.

I also tried pasting this block in `wp-config.php` (pre-filled FTP data basically):

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');
define('FTP_BASE', '/path/to/wordpress/'); 
define('FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/');
define('FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/');
define('FTP_USER', 'username');
define('FTP_PASS', 'password');
define('FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org');
define('FTP_SSL', false);
```

But that also didn't work.

Tl.dr.: FTP works fine with FileZilla (can connect to server and see wp folder) however using WP in-house ftp solution gives an error.

I tried all folders setting ownership "apache:apache" as well as myUser:myGroup (Apache being part of my group). 
WordPress permissions:

```
find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

as well as

```
find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Nothing worked. I am really running out of ideas here.

[image]

Comment: I would retry setting the owner/group permissions as this is usally what makes the FTP dialogue come up: `chown -R user:group /path/to/wordpress/` ... otherwise look into `request_filesystem_credentials` function to debug what test is actually failing and preventing direct writing.

Comment: Set up a virtual host for your local WordPress installation and use it as "Hostname' for inner FTP. [Configure](https://www.unixmen.com/install-configure-ftp-server-centos-7/) `vsftpd` which never delivers a problem.

Comment: solution link for future reference...
https://davidegan.me/install-wordpress-plugins-localhost-linux-mint/

Answer (score 1):

After two days of head banging, found out it's the SELinux giving me the issues.

Usually i got a message from it saying what and why was blocked, provided with a command to enable the action that SELinux was preventing. Like when apache wasn't able to write logs to my virtual host folder... 
This time around i got no such message so it didn't cross my mind it was SELinux-s fault.

I ended up turning SELinux off altogether as i saw CPannel doesn't function with it being enabled (i intend to use CPannel or smth equivalent down the line).